# Open Meetings + Kurento. Video and audio doesn't work

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, kurento, openmeetings

After numerous attempts to follow online documentation and configuration examples via forums we are not successfull in establishing video and audio conferencing with apache openmeetings/kurento on Ubuntu 18.04 Server. When we try to work in LAN - all is ok, audio and video works. When we do login outside, web interface works good, but not works video and audio. We have opened all ports on firewall and configured 1:1 nat to server with open meetings/kurento. We try to configure stun/turn server Coturn on this server, but it doesn't change situation. Please advise if somebody able to assist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Good morning
I found this github site that can test your media server. I was preparing to use it by gathering the username, password and IP for the server when I noticed that I had made an ommission in my configuration of Kurento server. I had completed two of the three but omitted the IP address of the server. When I added the IP address and restarted the programs everything was working. Make sure you open port 3478 on your firewall.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNsQz.png)